# How I can call Observable.complete callback function? It doesn't work

Tags: ionic-framework, observable, angularfire2, subscribe

In ionic 2, (and angularfire2@4.0.0-rc.0, firebase@3.9.0)
I tried this code, but complete function doesn't work!

```
constructor(public af: AngularFireDatabase, ...) { 
  this.temp = af.list('/myTest').subscribe(data => {
    ...  // my tastks
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  }, () => {
    console.log("done!");  // I can't see this output!
  });
}
```

I already tried very many times, but I can't see "done".

In another function, I tried this but the result is same with first.

```
console.log(this.temp.closed); // false
this.temp.unsubscribe()
console.log(this.temp.closed); // true
```

,, What can I do..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularFire `list` and `object` observables do not complete. Their internal Firebase [refs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) remain connected, listening for changes to the database.

If you want the list to complete after the first value is received, you can use the `first` operator:

```ts
import "rxjs/add/operator/first";

constructor(public af: AngularFireDatabase, ...) { 
  this.temp = af.list('/myTest')
    .first()
    .subscribe(data => {
      ...  // my tastks
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    }, () => {
      console.log("done!");
    });
}
```

Note that complete handlers are not called upon unsubscription. They are called when the observable completes.

If you want a callback to be invoked upon either completion or unsubscription, you can use the `finally` operator instead:

```ts
import "rxjs/add/operator/finally";

constructor(public af: AngularFireDatabase, ...) { 
  this.temp = af.list('/myTest')
    .finally(() => {
      console.log("done!");
    })
    .subscribe(data => {
      ...  // my tastks
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution is perfectly run in my project!

Comment: Oh, there is another problem. At af.list, .finally() is perfectly run but af.object, .finally() is not working.

Comment: `finally` is not an alternative to `first`. Without `first`, the observable won't complete and `finally` won't be called unless you explicitly unsubscribe. If you use both `first` and `finally` the callback to `finally` will be invoked when either the first value is emitted or when explicit unsubscription occurs - whichever happens first.

Comment: I got it! And my code run very well :) Thanks for your explanation.